# Why is my program reading an extra entry from a file in C++?

Tags: c++, file-handling

I have a file named 1.txt, it contains 3 lines, each line is stored in an object of class `entry` as follows:

```
1* 10/12/2020 5:30 a 11:15 p 0 0 0 0 -----
2* 11/12/2020 3:45 a 5:46 a 0 0 0 0 -----
3* 12/12/2020 5:46 a 4:56 p 34.6 0 0 0 blah
```

and I'm reading from this file line by line into `Entry e`, and storing each entry into `std::vector<Enrty>records` like this:

```
void read_records(std::ifstream file, Entry e, std::vector<Entry>&records)
{
    std::string line;
        std::cout << "READING TEXT FILE CONTENTS..." << std::endl;
        while (file)
        {
            getline(file, line);
            e.read_text(tokenize(line)); // tokenize tokenizes line to tokens and e.read_text stores data from that line into e
            records.push_back(e);
            e.reset(); // this resets e back to original state
        }
}
```

when I display `records` after calling this function it gives me an extra Entry in records like so,
The contents in `std::<Entry>records` are :

```
1* 10/12/2020 5:30 a 11:15 p 0 0 0 0 -----
2* 11/12/2020 3:45 a 5:46 a 0 0 0 0 -----
3* 12/12/2020 5:46 a 4:56 p 34.6 0 0 0 blah
3* 12/12/2020 5:46 a 4:56 p 34.6 0 0 0 blah   // I'm getting this extra entry in records when the file only contains 3 entries.
```

Please explain why this is happening and now to fix this in visual studio C++.

Comment: `while (file)` is still true, because the file is in a good state until after it reads the eof

Comment: @Kevin, this seems to clarify it, i think this might be the problem, how to fix this though?

Comment: @PratapBiswakarma as in Ayushya's answer, replace `while(file)` with `while(getline(file, line))`

Comment: That makes sense now. And also thanks for the great reference @Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here might root from the `while` statement -
this will add an extra iteration from what you expect because this condition is only false *after* you've gone past the end of the file.

```cpp
while(file) {
// ...
}
```

`getline` reads a whole line at a time, and since EOF is not a line you avoid the unwanted extra iteration.
This is the correct way to ingest a file stream in this use case:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> records;
  std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt");
  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
    records.push_back(line);
  }
  for (std::string e : records) {
    std::cout << e << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed the probem, But can you elaborate more? Like why is `while (std::getline(infile, line))` better than `while(file)`? Shouldn't `while (std::getline(infile, line))` work the same way as `while(file)`?

Comment: @PratapBiswakarma -- the difference is that with `while (file)`, when the `getline` call fails because it has reached the end of the input, the code in the rest of the loop body gets executed; it's only after that is done that the test in `while (file)` gets done. By testing the result of the call to `getline`, when the input ends, the code leaves the loop immediately.

Comment: @PeteBecker Understood! Thank you! Can you explain how this method would be if I'm reading records from a binary file?

Comment: I mean in a binary file where we just write the binary data and no formatting like space or newline etc.